# Show jobs closer to my location/city

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Is it possible to show jobs that are closer to the city I have mentioned in my careers profile? Right now I see jobs from SF, QC, TX in USA. I'd love if it rather showed jobs from India.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing careers job recommendations in the feed is planned for later on, alongside migrating those links from being opened in a web browser to being handled in-app.